# don't work auto resize uploaded image

Tags: php, file-upload, gd, autoresize

This method allows uploading a php file and images, after you modify it so that the images are authored, it no longer works and the error comes out:

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8ED3.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8ED3.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F24.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F24.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F2F.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F2F.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F44.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F44.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F45.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F45.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F50.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8F50.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8FDD.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8FDD.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php8FE8.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php8FE8.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(C:\xampp\tmp\php9011.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 220
>
> Warning: getimagesize(C:\xampp\tmp\php9011.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 221
>
> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 227
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php:221) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bconocimiento\controller\solucion.controller.php on line 236

```
public function Guardar()
{


    $solucion = new solucion();
    $tamaño = $_FILES['Pagina']['size'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['Pagina']['type'];

    $ruta = "";
    if ($_REQUEST['Tipo'] == "software")
    {
        $ruta = "view/software/";
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['Tipo'] == "hardware")
    {
        $ruta = "view/hardware/";
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['Tipo'] == "red")
    {
        $ruta = "view/red/";
    }


    opendir($ruta);
    $archivo_name = $_FILES['Pagina']['name'];
    $extension = explode(".", $archivo_name);
    $num = count($extension) - 1;
    if ($extension[$num] == "php" || $extension[$num] == "html")
    {

        $destino = $ruta . $_FILES['Pagina']['name'];
        copy($_FILES['Pagina']['tmp_name'], $destino);
        $solucion->id = $_REQUEST['id'];

        $solucion->Nombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
        $solucion->Tipo = $_REQUEST['Tipo'];
        $solucion->Descripcion = $_REQUEST['Descripcion'];

        $solucion->Pagina = $_FILES['Pagina']['name'];

        if ($solucion->id > 0)
        {
            $this->model->Actualizar($solucion, $_REQUEST['id']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->model->Registrar($solucion);
        }
    }
    $nuevacarpeta = $solucion->Pagina;
    $directorio = "";
    $ubicaion = $solucion->Tipo;
    if ($ubicaion == "software")
    {
        $directorio = "view/software/imagenes/" . $nuevacarpeta . "/";
    }
    if ($ubicaion == "hardware")
    {
        $directorio = "view/hardware/imagenes/" . $nuevacarpeta . "/";
    }
    if ($ubicaion == "red")
    {
        $directorio = "view/red/imagenes/" . $nuevacarpeta . "/";
    }


    foreach ($_FILES["archivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {

        if ($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key])
        {
            $filename = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key];
            $source = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key];




            if (!file_exists($directorio))
            {
                mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");
            }

            $dir = opendir($directorio);
            $target_path = $directorio . $filename;

            if ($_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$key] == "image/png" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$key] == "image/jpg" || !file_exists($target_path))
            {
                $result =move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path);
                // autoresize image
                $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                $image_info = getimagesize($source); 
                $width_orig  = $image_info[0]; // current width as found in image file
                $height_orig = $image_info[1]; // current height as found in image file
                $width = 968; // new image width
                $height = 681; // new image height
                $destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $orig_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
                imagejpeg($destination_image, $target_path, 100);
            // autoresize image
            }


            closedir($dir);
        }
    }
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

it is saved in the database Name, Type, Description and Page, but the image folder is not created where a folder with the name of Page is created, where the images are saved, what should I change so that the method works again?

Comment: Please highlight line `211`. I have a feeling its not in this code. Otherwise it would have died with another message..

Comment: Jees, your edit makes me even wonder if you read the error messages yourself. Why dont you start with the first error message you're getting, track that and find where it leads you?

Comment: `opendir()`  ... Why?? You are not doing anything that requires that

Answer (score 0):

Once you run

```
$result =move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path);
```

the file is no longer in `$source` i.e. `C:\xampp\tmp\php8ED3.tmp`

It is moved to `$target_path` and removed from `$source`

So use the `$target_path` in all following code like

```
$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_path);
$image_info = getimagesize($target_path);
```